# Naver Share Button script include

Tags: javascript, social-networking

We're adding a Naver share button to our site. We got the script from their [developer site](https://developers.naver.com/docs/share/navershare) and it works fine.

```
<span>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://share.naver.net/js/naver_sharebutton.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        new ShareNaver.makeButton({"type": "a"});
    </script>
</span>
```

However, `new ShareNaver.makeButton({"type": "a"});` includes the button where it's placed. Meaning we have the `<script>` elements in the middle of the page. We would like to move the inclusion of the script to just before the closing `</body>` tag.

I can not figure out how to move the script to the end but still include the button where I need it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a look at the `naver_sharebutton.js` source:

- `makeButton()` calls `insertButton()`
- `insertButton()` calls `createTag()`
- `createTag()` creates the image/button DOM element

You'll notice in the template that the img created has the `id=naver`

Once you know this, put the script anywhere you like, moving the button should be pretty trivial; providing your custom code to move the button executes after the naver code to put it on the page in the first place.

**jQuery:**

```
$('#naver').insertAfter('#otherPlace');
$('#naver').insertBefore('#otherPlace');
```

**JS**

```
document.getElementById('naver').appendChild(document.getElementById('otherPlace'));
```

One thing to bear in mind is this `naver_sharebutton.js` file isn't hosted on your server, so whatever code you write could break at any time, should they decide to update their script.

Comment: It has to be `$("#naver").closest("a")` to get the button and not just the image. I don't really like it, but I can't find a better solution.